# SwiftUI Localisation not working with @State Strings

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, localization, swiftui

I have implemented Localisation in my SwiftUI app. Everything works fine but I'm having issues with localising @State var. Localisation is not working and I'm getting only the keys printed out. Any idea how to fix this issue?

The value of `type` is already in my `Localizable.strings`

```
@State var type: String

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Text(self.type) // not working
        Text("test") // working
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can take convert the string into a `NSLocalizedString`

```
Text(NSLocalizedString(type, comment: ""))
```

or change the type of `type` into a `LocalizedStringKey`

```
@State var type: LocalizedStringKey
```

Answer (score 3):

When a string literal is passed to `Text` its type needs to be inferred (Since it isn't explicitly stated).  Literal text is probably a fixed part of your UI, so it is interpreted as a `LocalizedStringKey`.

When you pass the property `self.type`, it has an explicit type - `String`, so the `Text(_ verbatim:)` initialiser is used resulting in non-localised text.

If you want that property to be localised you can use the `LocalizedStringKey(_ string: String)` initialiser:

```
Text(LocalizedStringKey(self.type))
```